# Lags of buildozer apk

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

When I use Kivy Launcher there are no lags [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZrXObnERxc)
When I build buildozer apk there are some lags (I think it's multitouch problem)  [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyPmu7aKOJw)
I use simple Scatter widget and default buldozer spec but Paddles work different

Comment: What do you mean by 'lags'?

Comment: @inclement The Paddle is lagging. It responds slowly to the movement of the finger. Much slower.